# How to retrieve count of items in top level categories and including items in immediate sub-categories using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I tried ..

```
SELECT  c.* , (
    SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM item t
    WHERE t.cat_id = c.cat_id
    )ct_items, (

    SELECT COUNT( * )
    FROM item t
    INNER JOIN cat c3 ON t.cat_id = c3.cat_id
    AND c3.cat_id = c.parent_id
    ) ct_sub
FROM cat c
WHERE parent_id = '0'
ORDER BY name
```

but got Unknown column 'c.parent_id' in 'on clause'. Any ideas why I am getting this or another way to achieve this using mysql query? I can workout the numbers using multiple queries and using php etc though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to do everything in one query; sometimes trying to glue queries together ends up with worse performance (especially when correlated subqueries are involved). Two queries is OK; it's when you end up calling a new query for each row you've got problems.

So you could get the category items:

```
SELECT c0.*, COUNT(i0.id) AS cat_nitems
FROM cat AS c0
LEFT JOIN item AS i0 ON i0.cat_id=c0.cat_id
WHERE c0.parent_id= '0'
GROUP BY c0.cat_id
ORDER BY c0.name
```

and then separately get the subcategory items using a parent-child self-join:

```
SELECT c0.*, COUNT(i1.id) AS subcats_nitems
FROM cat AS c0
LEFT JOIN cat AS c1 ON c1.parent_id=c0.cat_id
LEFT JOIN item AS i1 ON item.cat_id=c1.cat_id
WHERE c0.parent_id= '0'
GROUP BY c0.cat_id
ORDER BY c0.name
```

And yes, you can join them both into a single query:

```
SELECT c0.*, COUNT(DISTINCT i0.id) AS cat_nitems, COUNT(DISTINCT i1.id) AS subcats_nitems
FROM cat AS c0
LEFT JOIN cat AS c1 ON c1.parent_id=c0.cat_id
LEFT JOIN item AS i0 ON item.cat_id=c0.cat_id
LEFT JOIN item AS i1 ON item.cat_id=c1.cat_id
WHERE c0.parent_id= '0'
GROUP BY c0.cat_id
ORDER BY c0.name
```

I would suspect the larger join and `DISTINCT` processing might make it less efficient. But then I guess on a small database you ain't gonna notice.

Either way, this will only work for two-deep nesting. If you need sub-sub-categories or arbitrary-depth trees in general, you should consider a schema that's better at modelling trees, such as nested sets.

Comment: This link could help: Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Comment: thanks .. I understand everything dont have to be in a single query, but wondered why it didnt work. I only need it for two-deep nesting so not interested in nested-set. Thanks for the above query, I'm having a play with it.